# How to Limit Current to a Hot Plate

Tags: current, current-measurement

I have a 1200 Watt hot plate that works great when connected to the grid but I want to be able to run it off of two deep cycle batteries wired in series to an inverter in an off grid situation. The thing is i want to be able to limit the current going to this device to have more fine tuned control on my battery drain. Testing with my killawatt reveals that despite the plate having a rotary knob heat control, this simply cycles the element on and off more slowly, so full 1200 watts on then off for a varying period of time. i want to be able to keep it cooking at say 600 watts continuous. Whats the best device to do this? Something inline on the power cord? Is there something that can handle these watt levels that i could build from parts?

Comment: Assuming it is a simple resistive load, you can just feed it with a lower voltage.

Comment: Or add a rather large diode so you only use half cycle.

Comment: A Triac might work but Rectified output with PWM would have a higher power factor

Comment: The large diode trick may do bad things to the inverter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A heater is probably the most "tolerant" device to drop power to, because no matter how you "mangle" the AC waveform coming in, a heater (being a purely resistive load) won't be affected in any detrimental way, and will tend to 'average" whatever is fed to it. This is why most of them just have a thermal contact that opens and closes to control the temperature. Now you can further intervene with electronics, but bear in mind that any electronic device to "drop" the power will also tend to lose some power based on the voltage droped across itself, multiplied by the current through it. It may not amount to significant waste, BUT it does mean whatever "part" does the "dropping" will have to be rated for that load, which will make it both larger and more expensive.

That said, you could drop the power by half with a single diode, which would allow only 1/2 of the AC waveform to get to the heater. As explained above though, that diode will have to be a large one to handle the current, and will have to be mounted in an enclosure that will not burn and will protect against someone burning themselves touching it. Assuming your 1200 watts of resistive load is intended for 120 VAC, you can see that this diode is going to have to be rated for at least 10 amps peak, and of course a PIV (peak inverse voltage) of around 200 volts, to account for the peak voltage levels of a 120VAC supply. (RMS volts/ 0.707).

Now if this heater were being fed by a pure sine wave source like your power company supplies over its "grid", I might also suggest you look for a self contained motor speed control rated for at least 10 amps. These devices usually employ a TRIAC instead of a diode, with a control circuit that allows you to dial in the exact power you want. Unfortunately most of those devices depend heavily on being fed by a predictable sine wave, which many converters don't supply. So getting such fine control might not be so easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** A canister of butane/propane gas contains a lot more energy that batteries, is lighter, cheaper, etc. Use a gas cooking burner for camping.

**Long answer:**

Your inverter might not like such a large load with a triac to dim it, so please check its documentation to see if they say something about triac dimmers. If it sounds like it should be OK, try a heavy-duty dimmer rated for at least 1.5 kW. I suggest experimenting with 250W then 500W halogen lights first, to see how your inverter handles this load.